# Dynamically add a product to Shopify cart

Tags: shopify

I need to add a product which is an extra cost for customer when s/he adds to cart products from different brands.
This is due to the fact that we ship products from different warehouses based on brands. So if user adds to cart:

- Iphone 4s (apple)
- Ipad mini (apple)

no extra product/charge added

if user adds to cart 2 items from different brands, we dynamically add a product called different warehouse extra charge:

- Iphone 4s (apple)
- Samsung Galaxy s4 (samsung)
- Extra charge - different warehouse

Question is then: How can I dynamically add products to cart if certain conditions are met?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Ajax API](http://wiki.shopify.com/Ajax_API) to do this.

In cart.liquid you can interrogate the cart items to see what products you have, determining what you need to add:

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
    Shopify.getCart(function(cart) {
        // add logic to see what items are in the cart and add a delivery one
        // if needed
        console.log(cart);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And then the user just deletes the extra charge going... pfft.. why should I pay that :)